# How to send data from Django script to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I made a script in my Django called "bdd.py" inside "polls" as you can see in this `tree` :
[image]

My problem is that this script is supposed to send some datas into my table torrent_infos in my MySQL database "TORRENTS" but i don't see anything in my table. Indeed when i execute the script it seems working:

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Documents/mysite/polls# python bdd.py
```

But my table still empty and i don't understand why. Have a look at my database:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE torrent_infos;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Size  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Hash  | varchar(60) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM torrent_infos ;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

And this is my script, probably the roots of the problem as you can see i take informations from the `.torrent` files in a folder and i'm trying to send it into my table `torrent_infos`. I tried some changes in the indentation without success. Any idea in mind are welcomed :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector
import bencode
import binascii
import hashlib
import os
import sys

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="root", database="TORRENTS")
cursor = conn.cursor()
path = "/home/florian/TorrentFiles"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for file in dirs:
        try:
                with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'rb') as torrentfile:
                        torrent = bencode.bdecode(torrentfile.read())
                        user = ("torrent['info']['name']","torrent['info']['length']","(hashlib.sha1(bencode.bencode(torrent['info'])).hexdigest())")
                        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO torrent_infos (Name, Size, Hash) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", user)
        except bencode.BTL.BTFailure:
                continue


conn.close()
```

Comment: Since this is a django app, I was wondering why don't you use the django framework for your script. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: You did not call conn.commit(), so your changes get rolled back when you disconnect. Still, I think you should follow Wtower's advice and implement this kind of things as a Django managemenet command.

Comment: @Wtower: Thank you, actually i was wondering were can i find information about it i will follow this doc :)

Comment: @Wtower But i don't really understand the advantage of using this

Comment: Why have you used django for this app at the first place?

Comment: Because i have to use html and python combined and it seems to be the best way to do it

Comment: Sooner or later then you would have to use the `torrent_infos` models in your app anyway, with a custom django command you can use the models easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite the above to fully use the django framework as a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/):

- Create a directory in `polls/` named `management`
- Create an empty `__init__.py` file in `polls/management/`
- Create a directory in `polls/management/` named `commands`
- Create an empty `__init__.py` file in `polls/management/commands/`
- Create a `bdd.py` file in `polls/management/commands/`
- In `bdd.py` define a command class that inherits from `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand` as in the example of documentation
- Create (if you haven't done so) the appropriate models for `torrent_infos` in your `models.py` and import in `bdd.py`
- Define the command logic properly using Django ORM.

In this way, you can fully take advantage of the Django framework, your app's models etc.